# Error trying to store new object from related model on form submit Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

guys I have this error y trying to fixing with no luck: (this is the error
Call to `undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::encuesta()`

just failing on insertion of Integrante,
Image works properly no errors

this is my relation on `integrante model`

```
public function integrantes()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Encuesta::class);
}
```

this is image relation on `image model`

```
public function encuesta() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Encuesta::class);
    }
```

this is my relation on `encuestas model`

```
public function integrantes()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Integrante::class, 'encuesta_id');
}
```

and this this my function action on my controller

```
public function store(EncuestaRequest $request){

    // Image Upload
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $file_count = count($file);
    $fileupload = 0; 
    $name = 'imagen_' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = public_path() . '/uploads';
    $file->move($path, $name);

    $encuestas = new Encuesta($request->all());
    $encuestas->save();
    // Saving Integrante
    $integrantes = new Integrante();
    $integrantes->nombres = $request->nombres;
    $integrantes->curp = $request->curp;
    $integrantes->parentesco = $request->parentesco;
    $integrantes->fecha_nacimiento = $request->fecha_nacimiento;
    $integrantes->genero = $request->genero;
    $integrantes->estado_nacimiento = $request->estado_nacimiento;
    $integrantes->encuesta()->associate($encuestas);
    $integrantes->save();

    // Saving Image   
    $image = new Image();
    $image->name = $name;
    $image->encuesta()->associate($encuestas);
    $image->save();


    return redirect('encuesta');
}
```

Comment: What does your `Image` model look it?

Comment: Hi, Taylor ,I updated above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Integrante model like this,

From:

```
public function integrantes()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Encuesta::class);
}
```

To:

```
public function encuesta()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Encuesta::class);
}
```

In the below line, you're trying to call encuesta() method from Integrante model, but you used a wrong function name(integrantes()) in the model. So, thats why you are getting undefined method error.

```
$integrantes->encuesta()->associate($encuestas);
```

Comment: thanks so much Rubanraj Ravichandran, now work properly